# bash redirect sub-shell's command stdout, <<<$(command) vs. < <(command)

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I was advised to use `command < <(command)` instead of `command <<< $(command)` without further explanation. It works, but I don't understand it. Could someone please elaborate on this?

In the latter, I think (command) in brackets executes command in a subshell. The stdout is catched with $(). Finally <<< redirects it as a 'here file' to the stdin of the command in the parent shell.

In contrast the former construct redirects a file's content with the first `<` to the parent shell's stdin. The brackets execute the (command) in a subshell. So ´<(command)´ will save the subshell's stdout as a file, or how does this work?

Comment: I've written an answer about difference between shell redirections before https://askubuntu.com/q/678915/295286 , so to follow "don't repeat yourself" principle I'll just leave a link here. `bash` on Linux implements both `<<<` and `< <()` are implemented in very much different fashion below the hood (one is seekable and the other is not). Whether or not the person who suggested the change understands it is a different story. We also don't know what commands you actually use to see if the suggestion is valid. If anyone wants this as an actual answer - let me know, but I'll stop here.

Answer (score 5):

`<<<` is a here strings. Similar to here documents: The word after `<<<` and a newline are passed to the standard input of a command. Syntax: `command <<< "some sentence"` (Like `echo "some sentence" | command`, but without the overhead of the subshell)

---

Command Substitution: `"$(cmd "foo bar")"` causes the command 'cmd' to be executed with the argument 'foo bar' and `"$(..)"` will be replaced by the output. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

---

Process Substitution: `<(command)` or `>(command)` is replaced by a `FIFO` or `/dev/fd/*` entry. Basically shorthand for setting up a named pipe. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution Example: `diff -u <(sort file1) <(sort file2)`

---

`command < <(othercommand)` # Same thing as `othercommand | command` but **without subshelling** 'command'. Uses file redirection (<) to redirect a file created by process substitution (<()). The space between < and <(..) is important to avoid ambiguity (is it a heredoc, is it a redirected PS?).

Comment: So I understand < <(...) feeds a substituted process's output to a command to the left by writing it to a temporary FIFO and the reading it, all without the overhead of subshelling.

Comment: Kinda correct but not exactly: `/dev/fd/*`  is not necessarily FIFO itself - it's a file descriptor entry, and pairs of file descriptors are passed between subprocesses in pipelines (which is what `<()` does underneath the hood, it's really series of pipelines). As for subshelling, I'm not sure where that comes from as bash 4.4 manual that I have says absolutely nothing in the section about process substitution. You may want to revise or research that a bit more maybe. In fact try this: `cat < <(echo $BASH_SUBSHELL)`

Comment: It's written `FIFO` **OR** `/dev/fd/*`